# How to run GIS codes through hadoop's prompt?

Tags: hadoop, gis

I am running a GIS code through hadoop's prompt in following manner:

- Wrote the GIS code in Eclipse including all the GIS jars (relevant).
- Went into the dir. where my eclipse workspace is.
- Compiled the code by adding all the relevant jars in the classpath. *(The     compilation was successful).
- Built the jar.
- Now running the same jar using hadoop: `bin/hadoop jar my_jar_file_name.jar my_pkg_structure.Main_class_file`

Now, inspite of the code being error free, when i try to execute through hadoop's propmpt, it gives me multiple issues.

Is there a workable alternative way to do the same without any hassles?

Also note, the gid code runs beautifully in eclipse. Since, I have to do Geo processing over hadoop, I need to run it through hadoop's prompt.

Comment: Please share your source code. and looks like you are not using -libjars parameter to specify the GIS jars when u try to run your code.

Comment: The runnable jar that I create includes all the jars of geotools and hadoop. Thus, I don't need to specify the -libjars as an extra parameter.